# Change a font family name in pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, ios, flutter, yaml

I used my own fonts on my flutter app, however when I set the fonts initially, I used a name "QuickSand" but now I want to change it to "Quicksand" and it doesn't change back.

initially inside pubspec.yaml:

```
- family: QuickSand
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
    - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
```

then inside pubspec.yaml:

```
- family: Quicksand
  fonts:
    - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
    - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
```

still the only way I can use this font family is:

```
fontFamily: 'QuickSand'
```

instead of:

```
fontFamily: 'Quicksand'
```

I couldn't find an answer online so I ask here.

Thanks

Comment: try using `pub get` in terminal and report me back :D

Comment: use flutter clean command and then run using flutter run command

Answer (score 0):

`flutter clean` command  on Terminal helped.

Thank you very much!